# Only Displaying "Ja" if the selection is Yes in Crystal Reports

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

In my desktop application I selected Yes which is in a radio
Button Group. Then when getting the print out I need to display as "Ja" only if I selected Yes. If I selected No, then need to disappear the text field.

[image]

First one is text box and second one is text field.
If select Yes I need to Display Ja in the second place. If selected one is false or other thing need to remove both these from the print report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula called: RequestAcute_result

Add this in the formula:

```
if {?RequestAcute} = True then 'Ja' else ''
```

if your paramaters is a string then you may need to use:

```
if {?RequestAcute} = 'Yes' then 'Ja' else ''
```

Happy reporting!
Adam from APB Reports (Norway)